# String pattern not matched in Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to validate this NIC number in Android Java.

```
NICs=NIC.getText().toString();
if((nameS.equals("")||NICs.equals(""))||!(NICs.matches("/^[0-9]{9}[vVxX]$/")))
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            this);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Warning!");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Please fill the above feilds !")
            .setCancelable(false)

            .setNegativeButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
```

My NIC="896201328V"
But it says NIC mismatches with the pattern given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove refex delimiters `/` from your code so use:

```
NICs.matches("[0-9]{9}[vVxX]")
```

instead of:

```
NICs.matches("/^[0-9]{9}[vVxX]$/")
```

**PS:** Anchors are also not needed in `String#matches` method.